# Integrate Custom Post Type with an ecommerce (Woocommerce o others) - WORDPRESS

Tags: php, wordpress, post, e-commerce, cart

How can I integrate an e-commerce plugin with an existing cystom post type in Wordpress?
I created a custom post type with a lot of options and taxonomies. Now i (the customer in very truth) need to be able to add these posts to a cart. Any solutions?
Thank you everybody already!

Answer (score 1):

I was also in the same situation and managed to make a solution.
I made it into a plugin. You can download it here http://reigelgallarde.me/product/woocommerce-woorei-shop-manager/. Just read the discription for instructions.

I would also like some feedback cause there might be some faulty functionality that I overlooked.

Comment: Reigel, this looks awesome! We will be trying this on one of our open projects.

Comment: @RevConcept yes please.. I'm having difficulty of continuing it cause I have no tester other than myself :D If I get feedback, I will continue working on it..

Comment: we won't be developing this portion for another month or so, but my team all signed off on trying this. Thanks!

Comment: This plugin is now obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your best bet is this plugin right here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/